# passing for loop to template

Tags: python, django

I have this function:

```
    for kid in kids:
      image = Image.open(os.getcwd()+kid.image_url)
      wpercent = (150/float(image.size[0]))
      hsize = int((float(image.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
      img = image.resize((150,150), Image.ANTIALIAS)
      img.save(os.getcwd()+kid.image_url)
     response = self.html_response('parent/i_am_new.html', {'kids': kids})
```

i want to pass img to templates so that that each kid can access img.

Template:

```
        {% for kid in kids %}
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:5 %}<tr> {% endif %}
        <td>
            <div id="child_link_login">
            <center>
            <div  style="height:150px;margin-top:2px; margin-left:3px;">
                <a href="/kid_login_by_parent/?kid_id={{kid.user_id}}">
                <img src="{{img}}" width="150" height="150" />
                </a>
                </div>

            </center>
                <a href="/kid_login_by_parent/?kid_id={{kid.user_id}}" style="text-decoration: none; color: #999999INSTALLED_APPS">
            <center>{{kid.avatar}}</center>
            </a>
            </div>
```

How do I perform this?

Comment: Could you show Kids model and the view of that template ?

Comment: You could add a model method, but I'm pretty sure you don't want to do this at all. If, as it looks, you're creating a resized image file from a web hosted image, you'd probably want to save the image and resize it at the time of creating the Kid object, rather than redoing it each time. Unless there's a particular reason for resizing the image each time ie. kid.image_url changes on constantly?